# can't pass a $variable in a header()

Tags: php

I'm trying to modify a login script from a File Manager I currently use on my website.

Currently, when the login attempt fails (wrong password, blank fields, etc..) an error message is stored in the `$errors` variable, and at the end of the script a function will include a file.php with `$errors` as a parameter, so the error message can be echo'd.

**What I am unsuccessfully trying to do is replacing this include + parameter($errors) by a header() + $errors.**

I have been around every thread dealing with this but so far I haven't found anything that works for me, I need some help : /

Here is the part of the login script that store the error message in $errors and include the file.php :

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['simple_auth']['username']) || isset($_GET["login"])) {

            session_destroy();
            session_start();

            if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {

                $user = gg::getUser($_POST['username']);

                if (isset($user['permissions']) && !strstr($user['permissions'], 'r')
                        || ($user['username'] == 'guest' && ggconf::get('allow_guests') == false)){
                    $errors = "Access Forbidden";
                    gg::writeLog('auth bad - not activated');
                }

                if (!isset($_POST['username']) || !isset($_POST['password']) || $_POST['username'] == '' || $_POST['password'] == ''){
                    $errors = "Enter username and password.";
                    gg::writeLog('auth bad - blank fields');
                }

                if (isset($user['akey']) && $user['akey'] != '' && strpos($user['akey'], 'otp-') === false){
                    $errors = "Please open your email and click on the link to proceed.";
                    gg::writeLog('auth bad - not activated');
                }

                if(!$errors && $user['username'] == $_POST['username'] && gg::checkPassword($_POST['password'], $user['password'])){
                    $this->loginUser($user);
                }

                if(!$errors){
                    $errors = "Wrong username or password.";
                    gg::writeLog('auth bad - wrong username or password');
                    sleep(1);
                }

            }


            if (!isset($_GET["login"]) && ggconf::get('allow_guests') == true){

                $user = gg::getUser('guest');

                if($user){
                    $this->loginUser($user);
                }
                // reload
                header('Location: '.ggconf::get('base_url'));
                die;


            }


            gg::display("login.php", array('errors' => $errors));
            exit;
        }
```

As you see at the end of this code is the gg::display function that will include the file and its parameter, the function gg::display is the following :

```
/* DISPLAY VIEWS CONTROLLER */

    public static function display($view, $params = null){

        require_once ggconf::get('base_path').$view;
    }
```

And last, here is the code inside the file.php that will display the error :

```
<?php if (isset($params['errors'])):?>
<div class=>
<?php echo $params['errors'];?>
</div>
<?php endif;?>
```

How can I get my variable $errors with a header() instead of the require_once currently used in the script ?

I found a lot threads dealing with this but nothing worked for me, also note that I'm not very experienced in php yet.

Anyways, I'm thankful for the help, and any suggestions are welcome.

-apatik

Comment: `header('Location: '. gg() . '?errors=' . $errors)`? you're redirecting to another page. either you store the errors on the server in the session, or you pass the errors via a query parameter in the url you're redirecting to.

Comment: thanks for answering, I tried both the session and and the url parameter but couldn't have it working. I guess I probably did something wrong. What is `gg()` in your exemple ? the header's url ? in my code it simply is the php class

Comment: gg is just me being lazy and not typing out ggconfetc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are redirecting to another page you should store the parameters via php session

```
session_start(); // this should be on top
$_SESSION['errors'] = $errors; // Add this after writing an error
```

And here is the view

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['errors'])):?>
<div class=>
<?php echo $_SESSION['errors'];?>
</div>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer that was really useful. I actually tried something like this earlier today but it wouldn't work. And on the first try yours didn't work neither, so I changed the header's location to another file with the view in it and it worked. So it looks like something weird is happening on the page I'm trying to display the error on. I'll do some researches and update. Thanks a lot

Comment: Allright, I figured out where the problem came from. In my post you can see that there is a session_destroy() in the script, and since the script is loaded at the same time as the login page, it would destroy the session and the parameter before the error is displayed. I'll figure this out. Thanks!

Comment: Just one more question, how can I delete the parameter after the error has been displayed once ? So the error message doesn't show up everytime the user goes back on the login page

Comment: unset($_SESSION['errors']); use after session_start(); on the top

Comment: Hum if I use it right after session_start() then it won't be echo'd lower on the code right ? Shouldn't I put this after the error message id displayed ? Thanks fot your help

Comment: Yes, why not! but if he did refresh it will not show the error again - only if he go through the functions also again. depend on your situations :)